# How convert an object to int

Tags: java, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to convert an object to int type....
eg:
   Object obj=........;
   int count = Integer.parseInt((String) obj);

when i use above code ai got cast exception.

Anyone know how to cast object to int...?

Comment: @Jisson may i know how did you initialize the Object obj=........;

Comment: I use Object obj =(Object)tableres.get("mCount");

Comment: @Jisson i think that tableres.get("mCount") gives you a number. why dont you cast to (int) or to (String)

Comment: @Jisson may i know what you are placing inside tableres.

Answer (score 0):

Use [obj.hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), to get an int that represents the object.  But what is your purpose?  The code you posted does not work - you try to cast the object to a string rather than calling toString(), but even then, unless the toString representation of the object is itself an integer, calling Integer.parseInt on it will throw an exception.

So what are you aiming at?

Comment: I call a  function, which in turns do some xmlrpc process and returns a hashtable.                                                  tableres = connector.checkin(table); this line thow the exception
   if (tableres != null && tableres.size() > 0) {int count = Integer.parseInt((String) tableres.get("mCount"));

Comment: Are you serious?  Don't you think this would be good to have in the question?  Anyways, I would assume the cast exception is from the fact that tableres.get("mCount") is not a string.  You should loop through the contents of the hash table and confirm that its elements are what you're expecting.  A bigger question - why would you keep the count as a String in the hash table and not an integer?  Are you sure it isn't an integer already?

Comment: toString() would be a better chose than hashCode() but I agree, store an integer as an integer not a String and you won't have this problem.

Comment: I just using the xmlrpc file created by some one else,I am new in java and Blaclberry...

Comment: *What* is not working?  @Jisson you really need to start being more explicit or people are going to very quickly start ignoring your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If tableres is a Hashtable, the values are prolly Integer, not int.
In that case, try:

int i = ((Integer) tableres.get ("mCount")).intValue();

Good luck, - M.S.